# Python, memory error, csv file too large

Tags: python, csv, memory

I have a problem with a python module that cannot handle importing a big datafile (the file targets.csv weights nearly 1 Gb)

the error appens when this line is loaded:

```
targets = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z), float(BG))
           for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))]
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gary\Documents\EPSON STUDIES\colors_text_D65.py", line 41, in <module>
    for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))]
MemoryError
```

I was wondering if there's a way to open the file targets.csv line by line? And also wondering it this would slow down the process?

This module is already pretty slow...

Thanks!

```
import geometry
import csv
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2

S = 0


img = cv2.imread("MAP.tif", -1)
height, width = img.shape

pixx = height * width
iterr = float(pixx / 1000)
accomplished = 0
temp = 0

ppm = file("epson gamut.ppm", 'w')

ppm.write("P3" + "\n" + str(width) + " " + str(height) + "\n" + "255" + "\n")
# PPM file header

all_colors = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for name, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('XYZcolorlist_D65.csv'))]

# background is marked SUPPORT
support_i = [i for i, color in enumerate(all_colors) if color[0] == '255 255 255']
if len(support_i)>0:
    support = np.array(all_colors[support_i[0]][1:])
    del all_colors[support_i[0]]
else:
    support = None

tg, hull_i = geometry.tetgen_of_hull([(X,Y,Z) for name, X, Y, Z in all_colors])
colors = [all_colors[i] for i in hull_i]

print ("thrown out: "
       + ", ".join(set(zip(*all_colors)[0]).difference(zip(*colors)[0])))

targets = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z), float(BG))
           for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))]

for target in targets:


    name, X, Y, Z, BG = target

    target_point = support + (np.array([X,Y,Z]) - support)/(1-BG)

    tet_i, bcoords = geometry.containing_tet(tg, target_point)

    if tet_i == None:
        #print str("out")    
        ppm.write(str("255 255 255") + "\n")
        print "out"

        temp += 1

        if temp >= iterr:

            accomplished += temp 
            print str(100 * accomplished / (float(pixx))) + str(" %")
            temp = 0

        continue 
        # not in gamut

    else:

        A = bcoords[0]
        B = bcoords[1]
        C = bcoords[2]
        D = bcoords[3]

        R = random.uniform(0,1)

        names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]

        if R <= A:
            S = names[0] 

        elif R <= A+B:
            S = names[1]

        elif R <= A+B+C:
            S = names[2]

        else:
            S = names[3]

        ppm.write(str(S) + "\n")

        temp += 1

        if temp >= iterr:

            accomplished += temp 
            print str(100 * accomplished / (float(pixx))) + str(" %")
            temp = 0


print "done"
ppm.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`csv.reader()` already reads the lines one at a time.  However, you're collecting all of the lines into a list first.  You should process the lines one at a time.  One approach is to switch to a generator, for example:

```
targets = ((name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z), float(BG))
           for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv')))
```

(Switching from square brackets to parens should change `target` from a list comprehension to a generator.)